# How to find default S2K parameters in GPG

Tags: gnupg, kdf

How can I find the default string-to-key parameters in GPG?  I am using it in Tails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Tails [source](https://git-tails.immerda.ch/tails/tree/config/chroot_local-includes/etc/skel/.gnupg/gpg.conf), no custom S2K counts are specified for GnuPG. This means you will be using the default for the current version. The [changelog](https://git-tails.immerda.ch/tails/plain/debian/changelog) for Tails shows that 3.7.1 is using both 2.1 and 1.4. For 2.1, the count [seems to be variable](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=agent/protect.c;h=16ae715e1b5ce792285053c7fcbe58b5ecf5a1a2;hb=refs/heads/master#l147) and depends on your hardware's performance, with a [minimum of 65536](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=agent/protect.c;h=16ae715e1b5ce792285053c7fcbe58b5ecf5a1a2;hb=refs/heads/master#l217). Version 1.4 on the other hand [hardcodes the default](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=g10/gpg.c;h=416d44e982dc4c72a0d5c0035b7f8266f1f301d9;hb=refs/heads/STABLE-BRANCH-1-4#l1894) at 65536.

The S2K version will always be 3 as is the case for all modern GnuPG setups. As for the default digest algorithm, for both [2.1](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=g10/main.h;h=453d1226ab375c7ce80028b0261a8f8f18914e61;hb=refs/heads/master#l51) and [1.4](https://git.gnupg.org/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=gnupg.git;a=blob;f=g10/main.h;h=a0b96f984133938c7d7c22887d7739029c42e885;hb=refs/heads/STABLE-BRANCH-1-4#l43), SHA-1 is the default. Note that there is an [open bug](https://dev.gnupg.org/T1800) that may make it such that the various S2K options in 2.x do not do what you think they will do.